# Genexus autoguardado durante evento de una Transacción - Gx X ev3 U5

Tags: genexus, transacciones

Tengo una transacción que tiene muchos campos (no quiero hacer todo en un Web Panel, porque es un trabajo muy grande pasar todo a variables y business components). Cuando se ingresan los primeros, debo guardarla automáticamente y si era inserción, pasar a modo edición.

Como puedo hacer esto?

Gracias, Ariel

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad es "partir" la `Transaction` en varias `Transactions` más chicas, e implementar una especie de *wizzard*.

Por ejemplo, en vez de tener una sola `Transaction` grande, podrías tener `N`, la primera se llama en modo `INSERT` y cuando se graba llamarías a la segunda en modo `UPDATE`.

Es posible que necesites manejar algún estado, para saber si el registro está completo o no, o en qué paso quedó el usuario, porque al hacerlo de esa forma el usuario puede salir de la edición en cualquier momento y dejar las cosas por la mitad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, podría ser, la cosa es que la pantalla debe ser una sola con todos los datos. Te cuento como es, es una especie de factura, donde hay un encabezado, luego items que a medida que se dan de alta recalculan los datos de la factura y se graban junto a la misma, y los datos del pie (totales que se calcularon). Cada vez que se carga un item, debe calcularse el encabezado (o pie) y grabarse. La verdad es que no se siquiera como hacer lo que me dijiste

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te sirva utilizar el evento "After Trn".
Acá te dejo el link a la Wiki de GX: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8045,After+Trn+Event,

Por ejemplo:

```
Event After Trn
 PrintAirlineCard.Call(AirlineId)
 UpdateLogAirline.Call(AirlineId, &TimeEnter, &TimeExit)
EndEvent
```

Comment: Hola @Mateo F, buen día,sería interesante que coloques algo de código que crees que podría solucionar la pregunta. Saludos :D

Comment: Es mejor agregar código a la pregunta, por si en algun momento la pagina que enlazas esta caida, aqui se tenga la referencia minima para poder resolver el problema

Comment: Hola Mateo. Gracias por tu ayuda. Te comento que trate, pero no supe como poner a la transacción en modo edición automáticamente luego de la primer inserción. Al final terminé cambiando la transacción por un Web Panel con Business Somponents, mas trabajo pero mas sencillo resolver el problema